# Calloc() not assigning zeros

Tags: c, struct, calloc

I want to create a struct which encapsulates a dynamically allocated array. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct IntArray {
    int *field;
    size_t length;
} IntArray;
```

Then, I have a function which creates such an IntArray struct:

```
IntArray *createIntArray(size_t length) {
    IntArray *output;

    if ((output = malloc(sizeof(IntArray))) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    output->field = calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    output->length = length;

    return output;
}
```

Here's the main:

```
int main() {
    size_t size = 10;
    IntArray *test = createIntArray(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", test[i]);
    }
}
```

---

I expect calloc() to initialize the memory with zeros, however the output is strange:

[image: screenshot]

---

I think these numbers are memory addresses, but where are they coming from? Every time I start the program, the numbers change but stay on the 1. and 6. positions..

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

I accidentally mixed up calloc and malloc here on stackoverflow, the problem actually occurs with the code above

Comment: 1) `output = calloc(length, sizeof(int))` --> `output = calloc(length, sizeof(IntArray))` 2) `printf("%d\n", test[i]);` --> `printf("%d\n", test->field[i]);` or `printf("%d\n", test[index].field[i]);`(uninitialized)

Comment: If you use the pattern we recommend here then this bug would not have occurred... `output = calloc(length, sizeof *output)`

Comment: 3) type of `test[i]` is `IntArray`, not `int`.

Comment: As is the tradition, you should compile with all possible warnings enabled and *fix any warnings and errors raised*. For example if you're using gcc, add `-Wall -Wextra` and possibly `-pedantic`. You'd get something like `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘IntArray {aka struct IntArray}’ [-Wformat=]`

Comment: @CodyGray the point of the site is to help people who clearly have no understanding of things.

Comment: @pvg No, the point of this site is to provide technical Q&A for enthusiast and professional programmers. A person with "no understanding of things" is not a programmer and thus should look elsewhere for basic studying material. That being said, this question is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: @Lundin yelling at someone they have 'no understanding of pointers' is just non-constructive invective. Weaseling about 'technical Q&A for enthusiast and professional programmers' (which is clear from context) does not change that.

Comment: @pvg We might have to endure a bit of intolerance from veteran users, since SO is constantly assaulted by a flood of crap. People who learn a programming language in the wrong order - likely because they are picking up bits and pieces from the internet instead of using conventional means of studying - are kind of wasting everyone's time, including their own. If nobody calls it out, they will continue learning in bad ways/from bad sources. To experiment with dynamic arrays before grasping the basics of pointers is doomed to fail.

Comment: @Lundin no, if you're finding it tiresome and onerous, that's fair but take a break. Internet point count is not some license for being a jerk.

Comment: @pvg That line of thought leads to "veteran users with expert domain knowledge should leave the site/go inactive, to give room for beginners with little or no knowledge". Which is exactly what has been happening over the past few years: the overall quality of the site is dropping. It is natural that people who have invested lots of effort in the site get frustrated by this and blame the newbies.

Comment: @Ludin no, it's just the 'don't be a dick' line of thought, a fairly universal rule.

Comment: Umm.. first line of first entry in the help: 'Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.'  Some might say that the jerks/dicks were those who could not be bothered to read the avaialble site docs before posting, I could not possibly comment myself....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to print a struct as an `int`. A good compiler will warn you abut it if you turn on/up compiler warnings (`-Wall` if you use gcc).

CreateIntArray creates a single `IntArray` with `field` of size `length`.
If you want to print the allocated `int` array you could use the following:

```
int main() {
    size_t size = 10;
    IntArray *test = createIntArray(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", test->field[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is of type `IntArray` but you allocate an array of `int. Therefore you get undefined behavior bugs.

It's also very strange to have a function called `createIntArray` that creates an array of int arrays dynamically, rather than just one array as I would expect. This is also a weird dependency, as it forces the caller to always use an array of arrays.

You probably want something else entirely. Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct IntArray {
    size_t length;
    int field[];
} IntArray;

IntArray* createIntArray(size_t length) 
{
  IntArray* result;
  result = calloc(1, sizeof(IntArray) + sizeof(int[length]));
  assert(result != NULL);

  result->length = length;  
  return result;
}

int main (void)
{
  IntArray* array[3];
  for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    array[i] = createIntArray(10);
  }
}
```